# What is mark_page_accessed for in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel, disk-io

I'm profiling my I/O-intensive application and faced some strange thing when performing `read`. Here is the part of `perf report` that confused me:

[image]

As can be seen it `mark_page_accessed` takes 20% of the file read routine. It does not seem to be related to the block device I/O which is performed by [`page_cache_async_readahead`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/filemap.c#L2059) which is not even called in my case. So all file data is in cache.

The [`void mark_page_accessed(struct page *page)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/swap.c#L373) implementation is commented with the following text:

```
/*
 * Mark a page as having seen activity.
 *
 * inactive,unreferenced    ->  inactive,referenced
 * inactive,referenced      ->  active,unreferenced
 * active,unreferenced      ->  active,referenced
 *
 * When a newly allocated page is not yet visible, so safe for non-atomic ops,
 * __SetPageReferenced(page) may be substituted for mark_page_accessed(page).
 */
```

So it seems it occurs if a page is either `inactive` or `unreferenced`.

**QUESTION:** What is the reason for this `mark_page_accessed`? Is it occurred because of the page is either `inactive` or `unreferenced`? What might be a cause? The page is already read from the disk so no page-fault (either major or minor) occurs.

Comment: Seems to be connected with ["page cache"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) ([buffer cache](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics)) and its LRU lists, check https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand013.html. Pages in page cache are listed in several structures to allow kernel to find some not recently used when there will be no free memory.

Comment: @osgx Thanks, very useful! But it looks counter-intuitive to me in the sense that the Kernel does `readahead` for some pages and after that the pages are still not "Recently Used". How is that possible? Or I missed your point?

Comment: readahead is not active access, it is I/O prefetch (optimisation), as IO devices are better for large sequential access (HDD of spinning rust are lot better for large I/O than for short requests; SSD are only several times better for large). Page cache tracking for activity is for userspace requests. No any page faults for read/write syscalls - it does copy when called directly (copy_page_to_iter, copy_user_enhanced_fast_string rep movsb), page by page. [generic_file_read_iter](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.5/source/mm/filemap.c#L1857), which calls do_generic_page_read+mark_page_accessed